# How to configure loopback to use access_token in the header

Tags: loopbackjs

I'm using access_token handling logic form loopback. It works fine, but unfortunately expects the access_token in the URL.

Can I configure loopback to use the access_token in the header custom field instead?

Comment: I would recommend using the standard `Authorization` header instead of a custom one. Loopback will search by default for a token in there.

Comment: Thanks Overdrivr! Is it somewhere documented? I mean, how it is expected to be packed in the Authorization header? Simply a string value of the token, or something like "Tolen " + value?

Comment: This is documented [here](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Making+authenticated+requests). Just put the token string inside the header

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Initialize Loopback Token Middleware
[check the docs](https://apidocs.strongloop.com/loopback/#loopback-token)

A sample code for enabling loopback.token middleware

```
app.use(loopback.token({  
  cookies: ['access_token'],
  headers: ['access_token', 'X-Access-Token'],
  params:  ['access_token']
  //additional keys (check docs for more info)
}));
```

It checks for these values in cookies, headers, and query string parameters

Comment: Where should this code go? Can I somehow instruct the API explorer to send the access_token in Header as well?

Answer (score 0):

Docs- https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Making-authenticated-requests.html

Pass the following header in request config (use your token)-

```
headers: {
    Authorization: '1vKbyJc9D2pJaE5sZWDqKxcJYlOfPab4eO8giuRMkfOxvoHKGUBRDcNvP4JwDIxe'
}
```

No configuration needed in server.